# how to replace object values from input values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I input values in input fields it has to set all values to my object but it doesn't do that.
So how can I set values of an object using input fields like this please make it workable...
Please make it as when I click the pay button it set all values of input to the object.

```
<input type="text" id="name"></input>
<input type="email" id="email"></input>
<input type="number" id="phone"></input>
<input type="text" id="billing"></input>
<input type="number" id="amount"></input>
<button id="rzp-button1">Pay</button>
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
var nameUser = document.getElementById("name").value;
var emailUser = document.getElementById("email").value;
var phoneUser = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var billingAddress = document.getElementById("billing").value;
var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    
var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_StY5fFXoMJvNaJ", // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
    "amount": amount*100, // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
    "currency": "INR",
    "name": "Trendy Cart",
    "description": "Test Transaction",
    "image": "https://example.com/your_logo",
   // "order_id": "order_9A33XWu170gUtm", //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
    "handler": function (response){
        alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
        alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
        alert(response.razorpay_signature)
    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": nameUser,
        "email": emailUser,
        "contact": phoneUser
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": billingAddress
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no JSON involved here, just objects. Perhaps that will aid in searching for existing solutions.

Comment: You may want to look at frameworks like Knockout, Angular, etc. that automates this kind of input-to-object binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the definition of `options` and `rzp1` inside the `onclick` function. This way the values are only read when the button is clicked and the `Razorpay` constructor can be passed the values when they are filled in rather than as soon as the page loads.